# Opening Iframe with Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, variables, url, iframe

I try to pass a javascript variable into the url of my iframe, but somehow i'm doing something wrong; can anyone tell me which mistake i make?

Code:

```
function getPrice() {
    var plans = document.getElementsByName('plans');
    for (index=0; index < plans.length; index++) {
        if (plans[index].checked) {
            return plans[index].getAttribute('data-price');
            break;
        }
    }
```

This returns; 50, 100 or 150 as value.

```
<button OnClick="javascript:alert(getPrice() + '.00');">Bedrag</button>
```

This button gives me the desired value which I want to add to the url of my Iframe:

```
<iframe width="350" height="150" style="border-left:0px;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;border-bottom:0px;" src="https://www.website.com/create-ideal-payment.php?betaling="+ getPrice() + ".00"></iframe>
```

Unfortunately the I frame opens whitout the desired output from the `"getPrice()"` function.

Which part of my thinking is incorrect to pass on the correct amount to the url in the Iframe?

Thanks for all the support/help in advance!

KR,
Alvin

Answer (score 0):

Set the iFrame URL in javascript itself.

```js
function getPrice() {
    var plans = document.getElementsByName('plans');
    var paymentFrame = document.getElementById('paymentFrame');
    var selectedPlan;
    for (index=0; index < plans.length; index++) {
        if (plans[index].checked) {
            selectedPlan = plans[index].getAttribute('data-price');
            break;
        }
    }
    
    paymentFrame.src="https://www.website.com/create-ideal-payment.php?betaling="+ selectedPlan + ".00"
    
    return selectedPlan;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="plans" data-price="50">
<input type="checkbox" name="plans" data-price="100">
<input type="checkbox" name="plans" data-price="150">
<button OnClick="javascript:alert(getPrice() + '.00');">Bedrag</button>
<iframe id="paymentFrame" width="350" height="150" style="border-left:0px;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;border-bottom:0px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In HTML Main**

note the id of the iframe

```
 <iframe width="350" id = "IframeID" height="150" style="border-left:0px;border-top:0px;border-right:0px;border-bottom:0px;" ></iframe>
```

**JavaScript referenced in main HTML**

```
  function getPrice() {
      var plans = document.getElementsByName('plans');
      for (index=0; index < plans.length; index++) {
      if (plans[index].checked) {
         document.getElementById('result').innerText = 50;
         return 50;//plans[index].getAttribute('data-price');
         break;
     }
 }
  // For testinhg this is the value will be injected in URL of iframe as query string
 return 50
}


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log(getPrice());
    document.getElementById('IframeID').src = "somepage.html?seed=" + getPrice() + ".00";
});
```

**IFrame Src HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST in IFRame</h1>
</body>
<script>
   function getParams() {

      var params = {},
      pairs = document.URL.split('?')
        .pop()
        .split('&');

   for (var i = 0, p; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    p = pairs[i].split('=');
    params[ p[0] ] =  p[1];
  }     

   return params;
  }
 var parameters = getParams();

 for( var i in parameters ){
   console.log( i , parameters[i] );
}
 </script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the input I've solved the problem.